# mod_rewrite help can't get it to work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the first time I use mod_rewrite and I can't get it to work. I have a website with bands and their IDs. What I want:

a URL `/bands/My_Band_id13/` should redirect to `/bands/index.php?bandname=My_Band&bandID=13`

What I have:

```
RewriteRule ^/bands/(.*)_id(.*)/$ /bands/index.php?bandname=$1&bandID=$2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure that you have `mod_rewrite` set to on.

Comment: Well yes, I did that.

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php

works fine. My headers are:

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the `'qsappend|QSA' (query string append)` [rewrite flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to your rule, ie.

```
RewriteRule ^/bands/(.*)_id(.*)/$ /bands/index.php?bandname=$1&bandID=$2 [QSA]
```

**UPDATE**: also, try removing / outcommenting your `RewriteBase /`. if this doesn't work, neither, try moving your `.htaccess` file into the same directory your index.php is in and adapt the `RewriteRule`, eg.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_id(.*)/$ index.php?bandname=$1&bandID=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: I'm afraid that did not change anything.

Comment: What I noticed, though is that the redirects work only for the root folder. I thought that the .htaccess rules extend on every subfolder. Is that not true?

Comment: can you try enabling rewrite logging, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog , with a `RewriteLogLevel` >= 3, and post the log here? thanks!

Comment: Hope you're looking for this:

www.metaldemos.com
78.35.88.57 - - [11/May/2010:17:20:12 +0200] "GET /bands/Kriegskarthaun_id12/ HTTP/1.1" 403 296 "-"

Comment: .htaccess file rules *are* propagated to subfolders , see httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html . they might be masked by other configuration directives, though.

Comment: no, that's *not* what i am looking for. that's from the access log - i'm looking for the rewrite log, and i posted a link to how to enable it. you need access to the main server or virtualhost config, though - do you have this?

Comment: I tried but everytime I try to activate the logging as explained in the link you provided, the whole server gives me an internal Server error.

The good new is, that I got it to work by putting the .htaccess into the subfolder and changing 'RewriteBase /bands' and the rule to 'RewriteRule  ^(.*)_id(.*)/$ index.php?bandname=$1&bandID=$2 [QSA, L]'